# Repository not found when building with webpack

Tags: typescript, babeljs, webpack-4, typeorm

I will try my best to make this question as clear as possible.

I am working on a back-end using NodeJS, which interact with a SQL Server database using TypeORM. I set up a build system using webpack4, where I build the TypeORM entities as commonjs modules (I have as many entry points as there are entities in the database). I have two separate webpack configurations, one for the main file and another for TypeORM entities.

The build process goes fine no warnings no errors, but when I run the main file TypeORM give me
`RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Foo" was found. looks like this entity is not registred in the default connection.`

I didn't have this problem when using Typescipt compiler.

Thank you a lot for your help.

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const CleanBuildDir = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

function localExternals(context, request, callback) {
  if (/\.\//.test(request)) {
    return callback(null, `commonjs ${request}`);
  }
  return callback();
}

const entitesConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'development',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  entry: () => {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/entities'));
    const entries = {};
    files.forEach(file => {
      entries[file.split('.')[0]] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/entities', file);
    });
    return entries;
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/entities'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals(), localExternals],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(t|j)s$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new CleanBuildDir()],
};

const mainConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'development',
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main.ts'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals(), localExternals],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(t|j)s$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new CleanBuildDir()],
};

module.exports = [entitesConfig, mainConfig];
```

ormconfig.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const entitiesFiles = fs
  .readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/entities'))
  .map(file => path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/entities', file));

module.exports = {
  name: 'default',
  type: 'mssql',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 1433,
  username: '*****',
  password: '*****',
  database: 'Foo',
  schema: 'dbo',
  synchronize: false,
  entities: entitiesFiles,
};
```

```js
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { Foo } from './entities/Foo';
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks';

function selection(table: string, columns: string[]): string[] {
  return columns.map(col => `${table}.${col}`);
}

async function job(server: string) {
  const connection = await createConnection();
  const start = performance.now();
  const foos = await connection
    .getRepository(Foo)
    .createQueryBuilder('foo')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('affaire.bar', 'bar')
    .orderBy('affaire.Code_Affaire', 'DESC')
    .getMany();
  console.log(`Done in ${performance.now() - start} ms`);
  console.log(foos);
}

job('ANY').catch(err => console.log(`Error in job : ${err}`));
```

babel.config.js:

```js
const presets = ['@babel/typescript', ['@babel/env', { useBuiltIns: 'usage', targets: { node: 'current' } }]];
const plugins = [
  ['@babel/proposal-decorators', { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
  '@babel/proposal-class-properties',
  '@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread',
];

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work by changing the options of `@babel/proposal-decorators` from `decoratorsBeforeExport: true` to `legacy: true` and add `loose: true` to the `@babel/proposal-class-properties` plugin.

new babel.config.js:

```js
const presets = ['@babel/typescript', ['@babel/env', { useBuiltIns: 'usage', targets: { node: 'current' } }]];
const plugins = [
  ['@babel/proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
  ['@babel/proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
  '@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread',
];

module.exports = { presets, plugins };
```